# how to remove a space from a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

My program is printing an extra space after every line. I want to remove the extra space from end of each line.

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
while count < (y//x):
    start = count*x + 1
    end = (count + 1) * x + 1
    for i in range(start,end,1):
        print(i,end=" ")
    print("")
    count+=1
```

**Input:**  3 99

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
.....
```

After end of the each line I am printing an extra space, How can I remove this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simpler approach where we print the numbers as a group and control both separator and end character:

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())

count = 0

while count < y // x:
    start = count * x + 1
    end = start + x

    print(*range(start, end), sep=" ")

    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Iterate over one less and then output with normal end instead of empty print

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
while count < (y//x):
    start = count*x + 1
    end = (count + 1) * x + 1
    for i in range(start,end - 1,1):
        print(i,end=" ")
    print(end - 1)
    count+=1
```

Comment: it's not working, it is giving this output.

    `1 2 4`
    `4 5 7`
    `7 8 10`

Answer (score 0):

Make a temporary array variable to store your values. Then print the array in one go as shown here.

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
count = 0
while count < (y//x):
    start = count*x + 1
    end = (count + 1) * x + 1
    temp_array = []
    for i in range(start,end,1):
        temp_array.append(i)
    print(*temp_array, sep = " ", end = "\n")
    count+=1
```